# Pushdown automation where number of letter `a` is at least as twice as letter `b` in the word

Tags: pushdown-automata

I have talked to my friend and he said this is the only place somebody could know how to solve it. It is the only exercise(from around 80) from exam revise I just do not know how to do at all.

Create pushdown automation for
`{w: #a(w) >= 2#b(w)};` and simulate it for the word `ababaaa`

`#` means number

Does any one of you is fluent enought in automation to solve it?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12011/8163

Comment: Don't crosspost questions on [CSTheory.SE] and [CS.SE].